# Unable to DI custom object in Azure Function App Startup

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "tester": "e=e",
    "ProjectConfiguration": "{\"tester\": \"tes22\"}"
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {

        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddOptions<ProjectConfiguration>()
                .Configure<IConfiguration>((option, configuration) =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"hello:{configuration.GetSection("ProjectConfiguration").Value}");
                    configuration.GetSection("ProjectConfiguration").Bind(option);
                });
        }
    }
```

I am able to print out `hello:{"tester": "tes22"}` but when I try to access it in another class, it is null.

```
    public class InitFunction
    {
        private readonly ProjectConfiguration _projectConfiguration;

        public InitFunction(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<ProjectConfiguration> options)
        {
            _projectConfiguration = options.Value;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(options.Value));
        }
```

option.value printed out is `{"tester":null}`

It seems like `.bind` is not binding the object properly. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the `ProjectConfiguration` properties as `:` delimited keys.

Assuming you have a configuration class like this:

```cs
class ProjectConfiguration {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ANumber { get; set; }
}
```

Its JSON equivalent would be:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    // ...
    "ProjectConfiguration:Title": "My App",
    "ProjectConfiguration:ANumber": 123
  }
}
```

### References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#working-with-options-and-settings

Comment: is there any other way to do this via json object instead of using delimited keys?

Comment: Did you try setting the config as an actual JSON object: `"ProjectConfiguration": {"tester": "tes22"}`? This works in ASP.NET Core, but I haven't used Azure Funcs, so I'm not sure if it works with it.

Comment: can i take a look at how the local.setting.json will look like? do i put that JSON object under "value"?

Comment: Like this: `{"IsEncrypted": false, "Value":{"ProjectConfiguration":{"Title": "My app", "ANumber": "123"}}}`. I've omitted some values to make a point.

Comment: I have tried this and I think "Value" in local.settings.json only take in string:string key value pair

Comment: Then you're stuck with `:` delimited keys.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @abdusco's answer, if you do not want `:`-delimited keys, you could bind your `ProjectConfiguration` directly to the `"Values"` section of `local.settings.config`

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        // ...
        "Tester": "tes22"
    }
}
```

```
public class ProjectConfiguration
{
    public string Tester { get; set; }
}
```

```
builder.Services
  .AddOptions<ProjectConfiguration>()
  .Configure<IConfiguration>((pc, config) => config.Bind(pc));
```

Theoretically the `Bind` method also has an overload to specify a key, presumably to use custom sections in the config but I was not able to get it to work.